# Modifying the behavior of link_to in a Redmine installation (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to modify the UI of a Redmine installation (Redmine 0.7.3.devel.2093 (MySQL)).

When you view a project in Redmine, it generates a list of all the subprojects for the project.

For example, **app/views/projects/index.rhtml** calls the **link_to** function:

```
<% if @project_tree[project].any? %>
    <p><%= l(:label_subproject_plural) %>:
    <%= @project_tree[project].sort.collect {|subproject| 
       link_to(h(subproject.name), {:action => 'show', :id => subproject}, :class => (User.current.member_of?(subproject) ? "subp fav" : "subp"))}.join(', ') %></p>
<% end %>
```

Which outputs the following HTML:

```
<p>Subprojects:
<a href="/projects/show/foo" class="subp fav">Foo Subproject</a>, <a href="/projects/show/bar" class="subp">Bar Subproject</a>, <a href="/projects/show/baz" class="subp fav">Baz Subproject</a></p>
```

We find that a comma-delimited list of subprojects is very difficult to visually parse. We'd like to have each subproject listed on its own line. (Any markup is fine -- UL, OL, or P tags on each link would be ideal, but a BR instead of a comma would be totally fine.)

What is the best way to make this change? I can't find where **`link_to`** is defined in the app; grepping for **`def link_to(`** and similar turns up nothing. I'm a UI type, so I don't really get how Rails deals with this stuff -- it doesn't seem to be defined in the view templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in the code you provided. Just change

```
join(', ')
```

to

```
join('<br />')
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

**link_to** is provided by the Rails framework - it isn't generating the links as a list - it simply creates a single link. The issue is the sort.collect and the block generating the calls to link_to

This should work, putting the subprojects into list items

```
<% @project_tree[project].sort.collect do |subproject| %>
  <li>        
    <%= link_to(h(subproject.name), {:action => 'show', :id => subproject}, :class => (User.current.member_of?(subproject) ? "subp fav" : "subp")) %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to point out that the latest version of Redmine trunk changed the project listing to use HTML lists (ul and li).